# ERROR: Data argument not used by format string

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4.6

Today I'm writing this program and I had has two problems.
This is the full code in Objective-C for a OS X Project:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        int numx;
        int quadr;


        NSLog(@"Inserisci un numero");
        scanf("%i", &numx);

        quadr = numx * numx;

        NSLog(@"Il quadrato del tuo numero %i è: ", numx, quadr);


    }

    return 0;
}
```

The second NSLog reports this error: Data argument not used by format string. Why it create this kind of error? In which way I can solve this error?
More over the run-time of the program finish unexpectly after that the output has written: "Inserisci un numero". When I insert the number requiry, the program not display the number squared as required from the second NSLog. Why I'm having this interrupt? Help me please. I what to understand what is happenend.

Answer (score 0):

The warning you get on that line is correct.

The quadr parameter you pass is not used in the format string. Each parameter you pass need to have a % equivalent in the format string.

Specify the extra parameter in your code sample conform line below:

```
    NSLog(@"Il quadrato del tuo numero %i è %i", numx, quadr);
```